# Querying a compound multi-index in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I am trying to efficiently retrieve data that is in the following format:

```
{
  "datetime": "1453845345493",
  "someIds": ["id2000-4", "id1000-34", "id2000-43", "id250-34"]
}
```

Specifically, what I want to do is "find all records that have happened since a given time, and of those, return any that have one or more of a list of Ids."

So far I followed the method [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20003998/how-do-i-create-a-compound-multi-index-in-rethinkdb) for creating a compound, multi-index using the following:

```
r.db("dbName").table("tableName")
  .indexCreate(
    "idDatetime", 
    function(each) {
      return each("someIds").map(function(id){
        return [each("datetime"), id]
      })
    }
    ,{multi: true})
```

This successfully builds an index based on values that look like `["1453845345493", "id2000-4"]`

But now it feel like I'm in a bit too deep, and don't actually know how to make a query that uses this index to accomplish the objective above. How do you craft that query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think(I maybe wrong), basically, we have two types of index lookup:

- exactly match: `get`, `getAll`
- range match: `between`

So in your case, it's clearly we cannot use `getAll` because you want to `find all records that have happened since a given time, and of those, return any that have one or more of a list of Id`.

That leave us only `between`. So let's find a way to model it.

I suggest to change `datetime` field to numeric instead of string. I guess you are storing epoch.

We will create index as you did:

```
r.table('t11').indexCreate('idDatetime', function(doc) {
  return doc('someIds').map(function(id){
        return [doc("datetime"), id]
  })
}, {multi: true})
```

Then we query it similar to this:

```
r.table('t11')
 .between([1453845345493, "id1000-34"], [r.maxval, "id1000-34"], {index: 'idDatetime'})
```

To find all the document since that epoch time and contains `id1000-34`. You can find the epoch of yesterday using either JavaScript or RethinkDB datetime function.

---

UPDATE:

While it isn't perfect, We can simulate either id with sth like this:

```
r.expr(["id1000-34", "id1000-4"])
  .concatMap(function(needle) {
    return r.table('t11')
     .between([1453845345499, needle], [r.maxval, needle], {index: 'idDatetime'})
  })
  .distinct()
```

Comment: This approach works well if I want to filter by time and then look up a single tag, but not if I want to filter by time and then look up multiple tags. An example I mentioned in another comment was "find all the messages since yesterday that contain either 'id2000-1', 'id2000-3' or 'id2000-5'." I've read deeper into the structure of indexes in RethinkDB and I'm not sure it's possible at this time...

Comment: Yes, you're right. That isn't possible at this time. However, we can do some work-around. I updated the answer with some ifno

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't you should definitely [check out this page on multi-indexes](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/#multi-indexes) in our docs.

An example using the data you have shown would go like this:

```
r.table("tableName").getAll("id2000-4", {index: "idDatetime"}).run(conn, callback)
```

This should get you all documents in that table which have `id2000-4` in that array.

Let me know if this works out for you!

Comment: The difficulty that I'm having is that I'm looking to filter on two things: a date range, and then to see if the object has one of many ids. For example, find all the messages since yesterday that contain either 'id2000-1', 'id2000-3' or 'id2000-5'.